# MVC - EF - Connect my profile with my Twitter (Not Login)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, twitter, credentials

I have an MVC - EF project.
I don't want to login to my site with my Twitter account (I mean the login to my site), I just want to see my tweets, and send tweet from my application. So no login to the site, for that my authentication is ok for me, just ask for Twitter credentials, save my credentials somehow to the DB for the future if I want get twwets (sync) or tweet something, etc. again and that's all.

Could you please help me in this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use OAuth and can avoid the login by getting all your credentials from your Twitter App:

1. Go to https://developer.twitter.com/
2. Open your app - it's the menu at the top right.
3. Go to App Details and then to the Keys and tokens tab

If you do the OAuth call with all the credentials, there won't be a need to log in. The exception to this is that there are some APIs, such as Home Timeline, where you must be logged in as the owner of the resource you're requesting - no way around that.

There, you'll find your keys and will be able to generate your Access token and Access token secret.

It you want to write the OAuth code yourself, visit Twitter's [Authentication](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview) page. If you do a web search, you'll also find many examples of how to code OAuth in C# - it's quite a chore. Alternatively, visit the Twitter [Libraries](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries) page and find a library that makes it much easier to do this. You'll also find my library, LINQ to Twitter, which is a free LINQ provider for the Twitter API and takes care of all the OAuth complexity for you.